# Comparing UIViews

Tags: objective-c, uiview, compare

I have the following (simplified) piece of code:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithView:(UIView *)theView{

    if ([theView isEqual:myFirstView]) {
        //do something;
    }else{
        //do something else;
         }
}
```

I would expect that, depending on what View I send to this method, either "myFirstView" or "mySecondView", I would get different results. However, the condition always turns out FALSE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass;`
`- (BOOL)isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also compare by taking tag values for both uiviews as below,

```
myfirstview.tag = 1;
mysecondview.tag = 2;
```

now call your method by passing your UIView i.e myfirstview or mysecondview
 and define your method like below:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithView:(UIView *)theView{

   if (theView.tag == 1 ) {
    //do something for myfirstview
   }
  else{
    //do something else for mysecondview
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. Initially, I had trouble setting the .tag, but I found out, that that was caused by the @synthesize. It read "@synthesize myfirstview = _ myfirstview;" This syntax I inherited from the sample code I based my project on. I reduced it to "@synthesize myfirstview" and now it works. I haven't got a clue though, what this syntax means, but the reduction doesn't seem to influence the functionality. Quite likely, this change would make Hamang's and Tarun's suggestion work as well...

Answer (score 0):

As Hemang answered.. you should check it using isKindOfClass or isMemberOfClass.
If you compare it using isEqual it will compare the object addresses.

Comment: By using either 'isKindOfClass' or 'isMemberOfClass', I get the following warning: 
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImageView *__strong' to parameter of type 'Class'. I use this syntax:if ([theView isMemberOfClass:myFirstView]) {